# Reading text file character by character into a 2d char[][] array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to read in a text file called test.txt. the first line of the text file are two integers. these integers tell you the rows and columns of the 2D char array. The rest of the file contains characters. the file looks a bit like: 4 4 FILE WITH SOME INFO except vertically on top of one another not horizontally. I must then read each of the rest of the contents of the file into the 2D char[][] array using nested for loops. I am not supposed to copy from one array to another. This is the code I have so far. I'm having trouble reading each character line by line into my 2D char array.  Help been working at this for hours.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
{



    File inFile = new File("test.txt");                                 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);     
    String[] size = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");         

    char[][] array = new char[Integer.parseInt(size[0])][Integer.parseInt(size[1])];

    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
        for(int s = 0; s < array[k].length; s++){
            System.out.print(array[k][s] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

     scanner.close();


}
```

}

Comment: The file format isn't clear enough. Can you paste the file into the question?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Why would you use nextInt() to read characters? The name of the method itself makes it obvious that it doesn't read characters. The javadoc confirms it.

Comment: @JB Nizet the nextInt() is to read the first line in the text file. Which are indeed integers.

Comment: No. You're not reading anything other than ints: `array[i][j] = (char) scanner.nextInt();`.

Comment: @JBNizet ohh I thought you were talking about reading my rows and columns. But yes that is where I am lost. I wasnt sure how to read the rest of the file since there is not nextChar() method in java

Comment: If you want help, answer the questions. What's the format of your file?

Comment: @JBNizet file format is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly - file format is something like

```
4 4
FILE
WITH
SOME
INFO
```

Modify as below

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);     
    String[] size = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");         

    char[][] array = new char[Integer.parseInt(size[0])][Integer.parseInt(size[1])];

    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    }
```

Above code is for initialization of you char array. In order to print the same you can do something like

```
Arrays.deepToString(array);
```

Comment: you cannot however assign an int array and then read a string. int[] size = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");

Answer (score 0):

Copying Tirath´s file format:

4 4
FILE
WITH
SOME
INFO

I would pass it into a 2d array as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    char[][] receptor = null;   //receptor 2d array
    char[] lineArray = null;    //receptor array for a line

    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = " ";

    try{
    fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        line = br.readLine();//initializes line reading the first line with the index
        int i = (int) (line.toCharArray()[0]-48); //we convert line to a char array and get the fist index (i) //48 = '0' at ASCII
        int j = (int)(line.toCharArray()[1]-48); // ... get the second index(j)

        receptor = new char[i][j];  //we can create our 2d receptor array using both index

        for(i=0; i<receptor.length;i++){
                line = br.readLine(); //1 line = 1 row
                lineArray = line.toCharArray(); //pass line (String) to char array
            for(j=0; j<receptor[0].length; j++){ //notice that we loop using the length of i=0
                receptor[i][j]=lineArray[j];    //we initialize our 2d array after reading each line
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("I/O error");
    }finally{
        try {
            if(fr !=null){
            br.close();
            fr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } //end try-catch-finally
}
```