# How do you convert a text file into a 2D character array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, character

I am trying to convert a text file into a 2 dimensional character array. I am part of the way there but the last line of my array is not fully correct. Here's my code:

```
protected void readMap(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    char[] chars;
    int lines=0;
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        lines++;
    }
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
        chars = new char[(int) file.length()];
        reader.read(chars);
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    int columns = ((int) file.length())/lines;     

    map = new char[lines][columns];
    for(int i=0; i<lines;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
           map[i][j] = chars[j%columns+i*columns];
        }
    }

    for(int ro=0; ro<map.length; ro++){
                for(int colum=0; colum<(map[0].length); colum++){
                    System.out.print(map[ro][colum]);
                }
            }
    return null;
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
##########################
#........................#
#.....###........###.....#
#......G..........G......#
#........................#
#...........E............#
#......G.........G.......#
#........G.....G.........#
#..........###...........#
#........................# 
#################
                 ^missing #'s here
```

I'm very confused on why this is occuring. I've tried changing how I print the array but i'm pretty sure its how its to do with how i've converted the 1d 'chars' array to the 2d 'map' array.
I'm really lost so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading text file character by character into a 2d char\[\]\[\] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567561/reading-text-file-character-by-character-into-a-2d-char-array)

Comment: @vinS I have tried the answer from that question and the line of code: char[][] array = new char[Integer.parseInt(size[0])][Integer.parseInt(size[1])];  is not what i need due my text file being characters only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your file looks something like this

```
##########################
#........................#
#.....###........###.....#
#......G..........G......#
#........................#
#...........E............#
#......G.........G.......#
#........G.....G.........#
#..........###...........#
#........................#
##########################
```

If you print the file length, you will see that the file length is `296`

As Your code `row = 11` and `columns = 26`

When you are copying to map you are copying up to `11 * 26 = 286`

Try the **UPDATED** code below

```
public void readMap(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int lines = 0, columns = 0;
    String str;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null && str.length() != 0) {
        lines++;
        columns = Math.max(columns, str.length()); // as it's not fixed
        lineList.add(str);
    }
    System.out.println("Row : " + lines);
    System.out.println("Columns : " + columns);

    char[][] map = new char[lines][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        String currentLine = lineList.get(i);
        int idx = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < currentLine.length(); j++) {
            map[i][j] = currentLine.charAt(idx++);
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < map.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < (map[0].length); c++) {
            System.out.print(map[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 306" at the line "map[i][j] = chars[idx];". Did you experience this? Thank you :)

Comment: By any chance, your file length is greater than 296?
I printed it on above code, you can check from there.

Comment: I copied all your code and map and this is what I get "Row : 11
File Len : 306
Columns : 28"

Comment: The file I posted above has the length of 296. I guess your files contains some NEW LINE character after every line.

Comment: That would make sense...What program did you use to convert the data to a text file?

Comment: I didn't use any program, Just copy and wrote the text file for testing

Comment: Just copied the text into Notepad++ and per new line it adds 2 more to the length so when the text is one line its length is 286 but when on different lines its 306. How do you think i could bypass this problem?

Comment: @brodingoson updated the code, please try now and let me know the result.

Comment: You read my mind...in a way. I figured it out by converting the 1d char array to a string and then replacing the new lines and then converting that string into a 2d array. Your way is a lot neater and efficient. Finally done this!! Thank you so much for the help, very appreciated! Have a good day sir

Comment: I'm glad to help you, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just executed the code and the map prints as expected. The issue may be down to the file itself as that is the uncommon factor.

**edit:**
The results you have observed is because you may have a new line character, or other special character, at the end of or somewhere in the file. Removing this you should see the consistent map you want.

**Alternative**

```
protected static void readMap(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line = "";
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    char[][] chars = new char[lines.size()][];
    for (int col = 0; col < lines.size(); col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < lines.get(col).length(); row++) {
            chars[col] = lines.get(col).toCharArray();
        }
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < chars.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < chars[col].length; row++) {
            System.out.print(chars[col][row]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}//My rows and cols may be back to front
```

Few other notes:

1. You shouldn't be returning a value from a void method, even null (You'll want to return null if the return type is Void).
2. Your compiler may complain if you don't initialize chars initially, as mine did. `char[] chars = null;` would do it in this scenario.

Comment: That's so odd. I just made another program and the same problem is occurring. Could you tell me what you are using to compile your java programs and how you saved your text file? This is so strange! Also thank you for your tips :) Also did you change any of my code other than what you've already said?

Comment: No other changes were made and I saved the file as data.txt using jdk1.8.0_92. How have you got the data in the file?
Is there any reason why you are chose to read in character when you had just read in by line to get the file length? Your algorithm would work, but overly complex.

Comment: the data is simply in a text file from Notepad, could you by any chance tell me the file length of your text file is? Thank you.

Comment: I get a file length of 297. If you have a new line character at the end it will produce the results you have observed in your initial post. As I have mentioned, your approach is far from optimal if all you are wanting to do is read in the data.

Comment: I just need to data be held in a 2d array and thats it :/

Comment: I've written a solution that should work. Give that a good if you are still having problems.